# How to use a file that was created in the same script

Tags: python, pygame, osmnx

I am trying to get OSMNx map as an image and then use the same image as a pygame background image

This is what I tried:

```py
import osmnx as ox
import pygame
from IPython.display import Image

ox.config(log_file=True,log_console=True,use_cache=True)

img_folder='image'; extension='png'; size=700

place='Prague'
point=(50.0908,14.4009) 
fig,ax=ox.plot_figure_ground(point=point,filename=place,network_type='all',dpi=150)
Image('{}/{}.{}'.format(img_folder,place,extension),height=size,width=size)

SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT = size, size
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Top Down Car Using OOP')
pygame.image.load(Image('{}/{}.{}'.format(img_folder,place,extension)))
```

The script creates three folders: logs, cache, and images, I want to reach the image from the folder images, but it cannot find the path
Thank you very much

Comment: Did you verify the image file exist? Do you handle the slash / backslash in linux/windows?

Comment: yes, when I comment out the section from SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT and below there are generated those three folders and in the image folder, there is requested image... If you want the exact error it shows it is this: Exception has occurred: error
Can't seek in this data source. Concerning the slash/backslash, I am afraid I have to say that I am not familiar with it

Comment: Are u on windows?

Comment: Yes, I am on Windows

Comment: i meant that sometimes the linux path (with /) are not well recognized on windows that uses (\).. this is a common pitfall that is solved by using pathlib Path that abstracts this from the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry, I was able to figure it out myself, just when I posted this question, it happened to me for the second time...

Here is my solution if anyone would have a similar problem in the future:

```py
import osmnx as ox
import pygame
from IPython.display import Image

ox.config(log_file=True,log_console=True,use_cache=True)

img_folder='image'; extension='png'; size=700

place='Prague'
point=(50.0908,14.4009) 
fig,ax=ox.plot_figure_ground(point=point,filename=place,network_type='all',dpi=150)
Image('{}/{}.{}'.format(img_folder,place,extension),height=size,width=size)

SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT = size, size
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Top Down Car Using OOP')
background_image = pygame.image.load("images\{}.{}".format(place,extension))

k = 0
Pixels = []
FPS = 24
running = True
screen.blit(background_image, [0, 0])
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
            # The user closed the window or pressed escape
            running = False
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
print('Done!')
```

Sorry for bothering you, but if possible, I would like to know what Lior Cohen means by the slash\backslash notation in the comments, I have to admit that I am confused.